# merb - no such file to load lib/exceptions

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9, merb

I'm maintaining an old merb applications (merb 1.1.3).   I recently switched to ruby 1.9.2 (via rvm) and did a bundle install successfully.

Now when I try to run the applications I get an error.  no such file to load: lib/exceptions

How can I fix this?

Thanks :)

Update:  there is an exceptions.rb file inside the applications lib/ directory.

Answer (score 0):

The load path is probably wrong. I would guess that lib/ is in the root of your source tree. You can eithe update the $LOAD_PATH to inclue "./"

```
$LOAD_PATH << "./"
```

or update all of your requires

```
require "./lib/exceptions"
```

Chris